# How would a time-dependent $G$ affect the derivation of the Einstein field equations?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, action

Let's say that the gravitational constant changes with time.  $~G~\to G(t)$. ​​​​ (It is essentially an isotropic and homogeneous scalar field)

If we were to re-derive the Einstein field equations using the Einstein-Hilbert action, how would this affect the derivation?

The action for this derivation can be taken as,
$$S =\frac {1}{16πG(t)} S_H + S_M$$
where $S_H = \int\sqrt{-g}~R~d^4x$.
In this case, $G$ is only a function of coordinate time, not of the metric, so I'm not sure how to proceed so it is properly included in the metric variation.  Could it be absorbed into $S_H$ or $S_M$ somehow before the variation occurs?

I am aware the $\frac {1}{16πG}$ is put in the action so it comes up with the correct constant to match the weak-field newtonian approximation. My question is more how would we deal with a variable gravitational constant, if that were to be discovered, and how we could account for that in the fundamental derivation of general relativity.

Comment: You may be interested in reading about [Brans-Dicke theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brans%E2%80%93Dicke_theory).

Comment: Yes, that is very interesting.   It looks like they accounted for a changing gravitational constant by adding a scalar field to the action.

Comment: What if the scalar field they added only changed with time, and not with space?  How could we continue the derivation?

Comment: It's not really consistent with relativity to have a physical quantity *only* depend on time. How does a value of $G$ outside my light cone know to be *exactly* the same value as a point at my location? The only way would be to break locality, and therefore causality.

Comment: that's a fair point.   What if we instead said that G is homogeneous and isotropic, and therefore can be treated as only a function of time?